# "SyntaxError: Unexpected Token" when running

Tags: javascript, node.js

[A Photo Of The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjVRV.png)

I do not understand why it is not running, I keep receiving this error

});
^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
```

Comment: Please [don't post your code as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), copy and paste it into the text of your question and format it using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you didn't respect the "don't post images" rule, I'll try giving you an answer.

I see in the image that at line 30 you have an `else` that is not closed, and the next character is a `}`, so it may be that causing the problem. You should write `else {}` in order to make the code run.

To avoid this kind of silly errors, try using something like ESLint: I see you're using Atom Editor, there's an atom package for that ([link](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint))